# Install / Test / Rollback an installation on a ASP.NET Core / Node JS application?

Tags: asp.net, windows, git, git-bash, continuous-deployment

The best way that I know of to test changes to a system is to have a production and test server, but that's not always possible, and sometimes it even has to be deployed to Windows.

Considering that there are binary .dll files involved in a Windows installation, is there a way to use git bash to deploy a revision of the software to a UNC share on a server without installing git on the server in question?

Are binaries going to cause issues being stored in a git repo if we deploy them in this manner?

Comment: You typically deploys server apps via an automated build/release process. Whether that tool uses Git depends on the specific tool you pick.

Comment: @mason Yeah I understand this isn't "actual" continuous integration / deployment.